# Module Url Working On Localhost But Not Working On Server

Tags: url-rewriting, yii, url-routing

i have generated a module admin by gii and add module based authentication.application is running on virtual host as

```
www.localhost.com
```

and it module is working fine in localhost by url

```
www.localhost.com/admin
```

or

```
www.localhost.com/admin/default
```

but when i upload module on server and access by url it give error 404.
i have checked it on another server also.
my config/main.php as

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                    'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
                    'rules'=>array(
                            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    ),
            ),
```

and .htaccess file as

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Please tell me what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to rewrite your base path. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: and check that mod_rewrite is even loaded.